# Show a react-toastify toast after navigating to another page

Tags: reactjs, navigation, react-router-dom, onsubmit, react-toastify

I have this function that submits data to an API call function on submit and then with the successdata it shows a toast. As the next step I made it to navigate to another page and to show the toast. But it only navigates and doesn't show the toast.

```html
const submitHandler = () => {
    updatePatient(
      data,
      (successData: any) => {
        toast.success(successData, {
          position: "top-right",
          autoClose: 5000,
          hideProgressBar: true,
          closeOnClick: false,
          pauseOnHover: true,
          draggable: true,
          progress: undefined,
          theme: "light",
        });
        navigate("/allpatients");
      },
      (errorData: any) => console.log(errorData)
    );
  };
```

Toastcontainer on navigated route

```html
<ToastContainer
        position="top-right"
        autoClose={5000}
        hideProgressBar
        newestOnTop={false}
        closeOnClick={false}
        rtl={false}
        pauseOnFocusLoss={false}
        draggable
        pauseOnHover
        theme="light"
      />
```

I tried the answers of the similar questions first but didn't work. I have a toastcontainer on the page I'm navigating.

I tried removing navigation and then it works fine. But I need the navigation.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please [edit] the post to include a more complete [mcve]? We can't really help diagnose code we can't see.

Comment: The entire component this submit handler belongs to, maybe its parent component, all the way up the ReactTree to the toast container, the routes, and the target routed component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a settimeout of 1ms and it works. Feels like a hack but it looks fine.

```html
const submitHandler = () => {
    updatePatient(
      data,
      (successData: any) => {
        navigate("/allpatients");
        setTimeout(() => {
          toast.success(successData, {
            position: "top-right",
            autoClose: 5000,
            hideProgressBar: true,
            closeOnClick: false,
            pauseOnHover: true,
            draggable: true,
            progress: undefined,
            theme: "light",
          });
        }, 1);
      },
      (errorData: any) => console.log(errorData)
    );
  };
```

Comment: Please try in an example first as it seem that after navigation, the code might not work.